# Could somebody view my question and tell me if my revision is good?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, question-quality

Recently, [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129179/making-keyboard-recede-on-ios-simulator) was closed as "Not A Real Question". I've since edited it.

Would somebody mind looking and advising me if this question has been properly revised, and if not what else could be done to improve it?

**Edit**

I believe I have been misinterpreted, I was asking as to whether the edit in question is a good way to ask a question in the future.

I am question-banned since my first 3 questions were terrible, 2 of which were deleted. I am trying to recover from such, and therefore am trying to properly edit my posts.

Comment: Do none of the questions you've been pointed at answer yours?

Comment: With regards to that particular question, it's not that big of an issue, so I don't really see how you can make it significantly better than you've already done. It does seem close-able as a dupe now, but that's another matter altogether. I made a few tiny edits I think improve it a bit. But that's about it.

Comment: @Bart Thank you, I am trying to revise my question since I've question banned.

Comment: Then you might want to focus on what you're asking on SO. I'm not evening looking at the content of your last two questions, just the titles: "What is **the easiest way** to..." and "What are **some good resources** to...". That immediately screams "Not constructive" to me.

Comment: @Bart I edited the one about overwriting files, but at a loss on the second one, about good resources.

Comment: Looking at that second question, it's just not fit for Stack Overflow. Such questions are explicitly off-topic. No real rescuing that one I'd say.

Comment: @Bart Right now what would you suggest, then to just leave that one? I don't won't to delete it, and go farther under...

Comment: Just leave it be and keep your fingers crossed that it doesn't attract downvotes. Focus on what you can improve or contribute. Don't worry about what you can't.

Comment: @Bart Thank you, as for the others after revising them, is there anything I should do (with them)?

Comment: After revising them? Not really. Unless they are closed and you think they should be reopened. But that does not seem to be the case. The ones that are closed are justifiably so.

Comment: @Bart Thanks, any other suggestions? Sorry to trouble you so much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to [the question you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129179/making-keyboard-recede-on-ios-simulator) I think you've made it as reasonable and answerable as it can be. It's not that big a question, so I don't see what else would significantly improve it. I made a minor edit removing some fluff, but that's about it.

As for your remaining questions, keep an eye out on what you're exactly asking. You're a fairly active user on SO these last couple of days, predominantly answering questions. But perhaps you're moving a bit too fast. Take your time to get a decent grasp on what this site is about.

Make sure you understand what a good on-topic question looks like. If you don't, read the FAQ linked at the top. That might sound a bit petty, but I mean it. I have a look through it every now and then to see what it says, especially when reviewing/moderating.

Two of your questions had titles starting with:

- "What is **the easiest way** to..."
- "What are **some good resources** to..."

Without going into the particular details of those questions, their titles already raise alarm bells when it comes to their appropriateness for the site.

Asking for an "easiest way to" pretty much sounds non-constructive. Even if your question does not end up being not constructive, avoid such titles. Don't ask us for the "best/easiest way to". Simply state what your problem is, what you have done to solve it, where you failed and then ask how it can be solved. You can then evaluate the answers you get to see if one of them is easier/better than the other.

And don't ask for "good resources". We don't want to point you at resources other than this site where you might possibly find information on how to solve your problem. We want to be the site where people can find information on how to solve your problem.

Now, in this particular case you asked us for good resources on how to learn Objective-C. That is pretty much the definition of an off-topic question. We don't do such recommendations here. Have a read through the [books](/questions/tagged/books) tag-wiki for some information on this.

That said, looking through your other contributions you seem to write well, and you should have no problem formulating good questions, once you realize what is and what isn't appropriate for the site. So take your time to figure this out, improve your content where possible, contribute great answers and you should be able to get back on track.

Good luck.

Comment: Wonder who read this answer within 50 seconds....:-)

Comment: @hims056 My sockpuppet did.

Comment: And also accepted... :D

Comment: @Bart So just to be a real biotch here, and not stop bugging you :D Is my second edit, more constructive and answerable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137607/what-method-should-i-use-to-overwrite-files

Comment: @MarkRobinson Well, one of the comments pretty much says it: *"Don't ask people questions you can easily look up the answer to in the documentation"*. That might sound harsh, but it's true. The question itself still asks for "the best way". Don't do that. Tell us what you want to do, tell us what the problem is and ask how you can solve it. And even with questions like these, tell us what you've tried so far. And once you get an answer, research it. Read documentation. Figure out what it does and how it works. Don't simply ask for clarifications you can figure out yourself.

Comment: This all boils down to "demonstrate to us that you've put in some effort". The users of SO tend to get easily annoyed when users seemingly don't try to solve their one problems. We are here to help you solve your problems. We're not here to solve your problems for you. If you keep that in mind, you'll be just fine.

Comment: @Bart Noted that, and fixed the other part, so I think I might be done...

Comment: @MarkRobinson Then I wish you good luck. Thanks for approaching this constructively. And good luck with getting yourself unbanned again. It might take some time, but you'll get there.

Comment: @MarkRobinson I had downvoted that question but seeing that you are actually trying to improve it and have put quite a bit of effort into it, I have reversed my vote. As Bart mentioned have a look at the FAQ and you will be fine.

Comment: @AshRj Thank you so much, this means a lot to me. I will examine the FAQ closely as well.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't know it, but you answered *this* question by writing it.

Have a look at [the history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/161610/revisions). The first revision was rather hard to decipher, it appeared as if you were seeing if your question could be re-opened.

That wasn't the case. As I saw subsequent updates come in (some merged into one due to the grace period), you actually wanted to know if your edits resulted in an *example* of something that would be well received in the future.

The first thing you need to do is ***slow down***. Write your entire question, proofread it and then (a little trick I like to do), read it *out loud* to make sure it's coherent and asks what you really want to ask.

You seem reasonably articulate, so I don't think the actual writing is a problem for you. However, future questions *should* contain more information on what you've tried, or where you looked for a reference on what to try yet didn't find anything helpful. You also need to spend time searching prior to asking, it saves all of us a bit of time and effort.

Your particular example is *answerable*, which is a definite improvement, but it lacks the other things that I mentioned.

I don't think your deleted questions are salvageable, but you should be able to improve the ones that were moderately well received to earn enough votes to lift the ban. Just be *sure* that by the time you hit the save button, you have fixed *everything* you can identify as wrong with the question and *ensured* that it reads as well as it possibly can.

Did I mention that you should probably ***slow down*** a bit? :)

Comment: Thank you, for your help.

Comment: No problem @MarkRobinson, good luck. I'm glad we could give you some pointers, and I'm glad that you came here to find some.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your revisions I try to tell what is wrong with them;

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14129179/1

This revision looks to me which there is no effort on this question. Looks like you didn't tried anything and you didn't any research. Also, in the end, for *Thanks* part, read [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14129179/2

Never apologize for this situation. We all here for learning.

> EDIT: I hope this makes more sense, **The keyboard in the iOS Simulator
>   will not go back down after I click on a textbox in my application**.
>   How do I make the keyboard go down. Is this something that must be
>   written into my program?

Writing this, looks to people you didn't tried anything. The question goes to "Make Sen" or "Not make sense". In SO, you can ask **spesific** programming question. Please read [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) a couple of times.

- https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14129179/3

You deleted the dublicate part in your question and add **Is there any good guide that explains how to do such?** This looks to me not a fit question for Stackoverflow. **Ask what you really want to ask.**

Also please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints which Jon Skeet explain about **Writing the perfect question**

Of course these are just mine humble opinions.